# How to light the air-water flow inside a transparent pipe from outside of the pipe?

Tags: led-strip

I have 17 meter acrylic pipe with 80 mm diameter. There is an upward air-water flow inside the pipe. I need to somehow be able to light inside the pipe so I can show the flow regime inside the pipe better. I can only think about putting a line of led strips on the wall of the pipe to improve the view of flow regime. Can anybody help me with this if they have a better idea or know of a proper LED strings or any other type of light that can work?

Comment: I mean thats probably the easiest way to do it. I'm assuming the outside of the pipe is in air and not water right?

Comment: This question is a bit too vague to answer as written. Whats the issue?

Comment: can you just have a white or black backing on half the pipe so the flow has something to contrast against?

Comment: Angle a few LEDs into the side of the pipe at a steep angle, then index match them to the pipe with transparent epoxy.  The light will refract towards the axis of the pipe when it hits the lower index fluid and then move along the pipe, illuminating your bubbles. Angle it right and you can make the flow light up with limited leaking out the sides.

Comment: Could you use a flluorescent dye in the water, and illuminate it with invisible (or filterable) monochrome light of a different (bluer) color?